Intersection Points of Sine Functions with Incommensurate Periods
I’ve been thinking about the intersection points of two sine functions with irrationally related time periods:
$f(x) = \sin(2x) \quad \text{and} \quad g(x) = \sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{\sqrt{3}}\right).$
Both functions clearly intersect at $(x = 0)$ (origin), but I suspect that they never intersect at any other point where both functions are simultaneously zero (i.e., no other ((k, 0)) where (k) is real).
My reasoning is based on their time periods being incommensurate $(T_1 = \pi$ for $f(x))$, and $(T_2 =  \sqrt{3}$ for $g(x))$, which means they don’t have a least common multiple (LCM). Since their periods don’t "sync up," I feel this should prevent them from having periodic intersections at zeros.
However, I’m unsure how to formally prove this. Could someone help with:

A formal proof or framework to rigorously show why these functions don’t intersect at other zeros beyond (x = 0).
Intuitive or "cool" ways to visualize this behavior.
Any other interesting insights into the behavior of functions with incommensurate periods.

Thanks in advance!

Feel free to customize it further if you'd like to add more of your personal thoughts or questions!

Elaborate the set of intersections with the x-axis for both cases and then equate the general terms each ...

There is a well known formula $\sin(a) - \sin(b) = ...$ ?

Thanks to Richard (in the comments), I know how to prove this using mathematics now. But, a very simple way to visualize this, that I found myself was as follows:
When both the functions start at the origin, suppose if they had time periods $T_a = 3$, and $T_b = 2$, then I know that their proportion is $1.5$. That said, I know that for every $1.5$ times the wavelength of $B$, the wavelength of $A$ ends once (This proportion is commensurate). Look at another example, $T_a = 22$, and $T_b = 7$, here the proportion is $\frac{22}{7}$, so we know again, that for every $22$ times the wavelength of $B$ ends, the wavelength of $A$ ends $7$ times. Which means that they meet perfectly at the point $(154, 0)$ on the x axis. But, for functions with a wavelength of $\pi$, and $\sqrt3$, can we calculate their proportion?
Their proportion is irrational, meaning we cannot express it as a ratio of two integers. Hence, the periods never align perfectly. While the ratio does exist—it’s a real number—it behaves like an endless mystery on the number line. No matter how far we zoom in, we’ll never find a point where the two periods truly 'lock in' with one another. It’s as though their meeting point is infinitely elusive, yet always there in the abstract sense. So, their proportion never "aligns perfectly". They’ll never meet at any point on the x-axis, except at the origin, where they started.
